# tesseract 4.0 is failed to detect less than "<" symbol

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using tesseract 4.0.0-rc2
while am trying to extract data using Tesseract 4.0 from image
of passport mrz

it gives me output like this

```
PNKHMHORKKEN<KK<KLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLRLRK
NO06370803KHM9410132M2609201N0000714729<<<58
```

which is not exactly I want, please help me for the correct solution for that

thanks in advance

Comment: The image quality near the '<<<' is pixelated, so the way tesseract 4 is trained makes < looks like L.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekJain any solution for fixing this issue?

Comment: I would recommend to remove that image, because it likely contains sensitive information. You can use an Utopia mrz image as an example or hide passport number from your image. Also I would recomment you to use custom font traineddata (OCR-B), you can find one for older version of tesseract somewhere in the internet, or train one for tesseract 4 by yourself.

Comment: I removed that image, it was downloaded from google, it was dummy passport mrz

Comment: Thank you @DmitriiZ. you made my day!,
it's working now

Comment: You will still have issue with MRV(Visas) where country logo often overlaps some letters which makes binarization part very hard. People usually use neural networks and custom letter detection for mrz extraction, but tesseract would work fine for some cases.